# Performance on Cassandra frozen types

Tags: performance, types, cassandra, frozen-columns

I have been googleing a bit about the benefits of having frozen collections vs non-frozen collections performance-wise but I have not been very lucky.

Can anybody tell me anything about it or paste a proper link to get some insight ?
Thanks in advance